# Remap Caps Lock to AltGr / Alt+Ctrl on Windows?

Tags: windows-7, windows, keyboard, hotkeys

Does anyone know how to remap <kbd>Caps Lock</kbd> to <kbd>AltGr</kbd>/<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on Windows 7?

Closest I've come to solving it is using SharkKeys, but if I try to map anything with <kbd>AltGr</kbd> it says SharpKeys doesn't know about the key.

Here's the old bug report about it: https://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/workitem/10375

I've been searching a lot, but all the registry hacks are how to map it to <kbd>Shift</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, nothing about <kbd>AltGr</kbd>.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found much better alternative: https://code.google.com/p/keymapper/

KeyMapper works very well and you can map absolutely everything. You can also save your mappings and .reg file.

Softpedia mirrors: http://www.softpedia.com/get/Desktop-Enhancements/Other-Desktop-Enhancements/KeyMapper.shtml#download
The EU secure link seems to work if you trust that they serve you the original binary.

Comment: Unfortunately this link now redirects to github where these downloads are (apparently) unavailable.

Comment: @robert Check my edited answer. But you need to trust that softpedia is serving you the correct binary. I don't know that, the original project seems to be vanished indeed.

Answer (score 2):

since all solutions I found were not working anymore (at least for me) on a current Win 10, this is what finally helped me (with a German keyboard):

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00
[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout]
"Scancode Map"=hex:00,00,00,00,00,00,00,00,02,00,00,00,38,e0,3a,00,00,00,00,00
```

the original tool that produced this key entry for me was this one: https://unclassified.software/de/apps/remapkeyboard
(i am not affiliated)

drawback of that software is that it requires admin rights for execution, so the registry key should be enough.